# UnicodeDecodeError with Jinja2 + GAE

Tags: google-app-engine, jinja2

I get the following error when trying to render foreign chars from a dict. Do you have any idea what I should do?

```
File "/base/data/home/apps/s~montaoproject/cap.354503891062679364/main.py", line 333, in render_jinja
    self.response.out.write(template.render(data))
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~montaoproject/cap.354503891062679364/jinja2/environment.py", line 894, in render
    return self.environment.handle_exception(exc_info, True)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~montaoproject/cap.354503891062679364/templates/list_jinja.html", line 199, in top-level template code
    {% for key,value in location_map_br_11_cap.items() %}<option value="3" >{{ value.name }}</option>{% endfor %}
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 9: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Here is my variable:

```
location_map_br_11_cap = {1: {
    'name': str('Toda Região 11 (ddd)'),
    'lat': -23.55,
    'long': -46.64,
    'radius': 294200,
    }, 2: {
    'name': str('Todo Estado de São Paulo'),
    'lat': -22.90,
    'long': -43.21,
    'radius': 294200,
    }, 1: {
    'name': str('Toda região Sudeste do Brasil'),
    'lat': -23.55,
    'long': -46.64,
    'radius': 294200,
    }}
```

I will try this with some hope that it will succeed:

```
location_map_br_11_cap = {1: {
    'name': str('Toda Região 11 (ddd)').decode('utf-8'),
    'lat': -23.55,
    'long': -46.64,
    'radius': 294200,
    }, 2: {
    'name': str('Todo Estado de São Paulo').decode('utf-8'),
    'lat': -22.90,
    'long': -43.21,
    'radius': 294200,
    }, 1: {
    'name': str('Toda região Sudeste do Brasil').decode('utf-8'),
    'lat': -23.55,
    'long': -46.64,
    'radius': 294200,
    }}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `location_map_br_11_cap` variable contains values that have names which are raw strings rather than unicode strings. Convert your strings to Unicode, so Jinja knows how to encode them when it generates the template.

Comment: Thank you @Nick Johnson. I wish I knew directly how to do it. I think I can just put a `str()` around the string to make it unicode or perhaps an `str()` around the whole variable

Comment: @Nicke `str` converts objects to byte strings. If you have byte strings, you can decode them by calling `.decode(codec)` on them - probably `utf8`, but that depends on your app.

Comment: `.decode('utf-8')` worked for me. Thanks for the help @Nick Johnson